# How to write own isnumber() function?

Tags: c, numbers, argv

I'm new to C and I'm thinking how to write this function myself. I take a parameter from command line, so it is stored in argv array and I want to decide whether it is or isn't number. What is the easiest way to do this?

Thank you

```
#include <stdio.h>

int isNumber(int *param)
{   
    if (*param > 0 && *param < 128)
        return 1;
    return 0;
} 

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc == 2)
        isNumber(argv[1]);
    else printf("Not enought parameters.");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What makes you think `argv[1]` gets converted to `int` ?

Comment: Your code won't compile without errors. Since `argv[1]` is a `char*` but `isNumber` wants an `int` (and is very poorly named: every `int param` *is* a number!)

Answer (score 3):

Read about [strtol(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtol.3.html). You could use it as

```
bool isnumber(const char*s) {
   char* e = NULL;
   (void) strtol(s, &e, 0);
   return e != NULL && *e == (char)0;
}
```

but that is not very efficient (e.g. for a string with a million of digits) since the useless conversion will be made.

But in fact, you often care about the value of that number, so you would call `strtol` in your program argument processing (of `argv` argument to `main`) and care about the result of `strtol`  that is the actual value of the number.

You use the fact that `strtol` can update (thru its third argument) a pointer to the end of the number in the parsed string. If that end pointer does not become the end of the string the conversion somehow failed.

E.g.

```
int main (int argc, char**argv) {
   long num = 0;
   char* endp = NULL;
   if (argc < 2) 
     { fprintf(stderr, "missing program argument\n");
       exit (EXIT_FAILURE); }; 
   num = strtol (argv[1], endp);
   if (endp == NULL || *endp != (char)0)
     { fprintf(stderr, "program argument %s is bad number\n", argv[1]);
       exit (EXIT_FAILURE); }; 
   if (num<0 || num>=128)
     { fprintf(stderr, "number %ld is out of bounds.\n", num);
       exit(EXIT_FAILURE); };
   do_something_with_number (num);
   exit (EXIT_SUCCESS);
 }
```

Comment: I know function strtol. I actually wanted to make it without it. And maximum number is going to be 127.

Comment: Then use `strtol` and check also that it result is `<128` (and perhaps `>=0`) and check the end pointer. BTW, 127 could be written as `00000177` (octal) or `0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000007F` (hex) by some strange user.

Answer (score 1):

How about trying like this:

```
#include <ctype.h>

if(isdigit(input))
{
  return true;
}
else
{
  return false;
}
```

**OR** more simple as **H2CO3** commented:

```
 #define isnumber isdigit
```

OR

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
int main () {

  //some code
  theChar = atoi(string[i]);
  if (isdigit(theChar)) {
    return true;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is written more simply as `#define isnumber isdigit`

Comment: @H2CO3:- Yes thats true. I just thought to write this way. Is this wrong? :(

Comment: It's not wrong, just superfluous, and IMHO it doesn't help much since OP has a string, not a single character (not like he shouldn't be able to figure it out himself, but anyway.)

Comment: @H2CO3:- Got that! Updated my answer with the simpler version as suggested. Thanks

Comment: Yes seen that, great.

Comment: All the answers looking directly at the codes, isdigit is saves so many headaches.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
#define MYISNUM(x) ((x) >= '0' && (x) <= '9')
```

Comment: Better use `isdigit` from `<ctype.h>`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you want to check if it's a number or a digit and `argv[1]` is of type `char *` not int so you should do something like that:

```
bool isDigit(char *param)
{   
    return (*param >= `0` && *param <= `9`)
}

bool isNumber(char *param)
{   
    while (param)
    {
        if (!isDigit(param))
            return false;
       param++;
    }
    return true;
}
```