# Checking if command line input is valid integer (C)

Tags: c, string, char, integer, command-line-arguments

I'm trying to verify that my program's user enters a valid integer in the command line.  I've run into a problem: It rejects ALL input.

Here's what I have

```
// Make sure input is a valid int
char *ptr = NULL;
long int input = strtol(argv[i+1], &ptr, 10);
if(ptr == NULL){
    userMinInt = input;
    minIntSet = true;    
}
else
    fprintf(stderr, "You must enter a valid integer for <min-int>. Using default value of %ld\n", minInt);
```

Comment: I think http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19206660/how-to-write-own-isnumber-function answers this.

Comment: @peter Ah, i see. So you don't check for null you check for (char)0;

Comment: what is `i` ? Make sure you check `i + 1 < argc` before doing this

Comment: @MattMcNabb This is within a for loop of for(int i = 0; i < argc; i ++)

Comment: @JayB `argv[argc]` is always null, so you will read a null pointer on the last loop iteration. To fix this make the loop condition be `i + 1 < argc`

Comment: @MattMcNabb  i will check if argc > i + 1 before attempting to grab it for input. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Code is checking if the end-pointer is `NULL`.  Instead, code should check for:

1) Does the end-pointer point to the null character `'\0'`?
2) Does the end-pointer differ from the start?

Additional checks below:

```
char *start = argv[i+1];  // maybe should be argv[i]
char *ptr;
// set errno to 0 for subsequent check
errno = 0;
long int input = strtol(start, &ptr, 10);
if (ptr == start) {
  fprintf(stderr, "No conversion done.\n");
}
else if (*ptr != 0) {
  fprintf(stderr, "Extra data after the number.\n");
}
else if (errno) {
  fprintf(stderr, "Number outside long range.\n");
}
else if (input < INT_MIN || input > INT_MAX) {
  fprintf(stderr, "Number %ld outside int range.\n", input);
}
else {
  printf("Number is %d.\n", (int) input);
}
```

Comment: I think, `if(errno)` should be `if((input == LONG_MIN || input == LONG_MAX) && errno == ERANGE)` -- `errno` may be changed on success.

Comment: @mafso Agree the proposed `if()` would work, yet disagree as to its need.  A call to `strtol()` sets `errno` on a range error, otherwise it is not changed: "The value of `errno` may be set to nonzero by a library function call whether or not there is an error, provided the use of `errno` is not documented in the description of the function in this International Standard."  C11 §7.5 3 and `strtol()` spec includes: "...If the correct value is outside the range of representable values, ... and the value of the macro `ERANGE` is stored in `errno`." §7.22.1.4

Comment: Interesting. The Linux manpages seem to contradict this (especially the code examples). Maybe it's different for standard C functions and POSIX or GNU functions? Anyway, I'm convinced about this case here. Thanks!

Comment: @mafso  I reviewed http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtol and agree with you about some potential contradictions on meaning/handling of `errno`, though did not find anything to support the "`errno` may be changed on success".  Did find: "determine if an error occurred by checking whether `errno` has a nonzero value after the call."  (IAC, this sounds like a good SO question.)

Comment: From http://linux.die.net/man/3/errno: "a function that succeeds _is_ allowed to change `errno`." [emph. not mine] I'll have a look into POSIX and some manpages, try a few functions from glibc, and see if I can write a question (if you're not going to do it).

Comment: @mafso Hmm "function that succeeds is allowed to change errno." seems to be constrained by C11 §7.5 3.  Look forward to your posting of the question.

Comment: ... or maybe it's not worth a question: http://austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=105. Looks like there are (non-C standard) functions changing `errno` on success (like [`ftello`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/ftell.html)), but only functions which aren't part of the C standard.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to peter, I've solved the problem. Here is the new working code:

```
// Make sure input is a valid int
char *ptr = NULL;
long int input = strtol(argv[i+1], &ptr, 10);
if(ptr != NULL && *ptr == (char)0){
    userMinInt = input;
    minIntSet = true;
}
else
    fprintf(stderr, "You must enter a valid integer for <min-int>. Using default value of %ld\n", minInt);
```

Comment: the cast is unnecessary, you can remove it without changing the behaviour of the program.

Comment: @MattMcNabb Isnt (int)0 equal to NULL in C?

Comment: not exactly. `NULL` is a macro that can expand to either `0` or `(void *)0` and it's supposed to be used where a pointer is expected. This has nothing to do with `*ptr == 0` though.