# Check if a char is a digit? (in C)

Tags: c

**NOTE THAT I AM A NEWBIE**

I've used `isdigit()` function before, but now I have an issue:

I need to check if (for an example) a `char` with the value `-46` is a digit. `isdigit()` doesn`t seem to recognize negative numbers (probably because of that **-** before the actual number).

Is there a simple line of code that can have the same effect as `isdigit()` function, but that detects negative numbers as well? (like an ASCII table range or something)

Let me clarify myself further: I have an char type array: `char A[20]` I enter each value manually (example):

```
A[0]= a
A[1]= b
A[2]= -46
```

Now from those 3 (ignore the remaining 17 - this is just an example), I need to check if any of those is a digit. -46 is a number that i`m searching for (to put it in another array), so my question is how do I check if that -46 "is a digit"?

Comment: isdigit takes just one char argument at a time.

Comment: `isdigit` will work fine. Presumably `if (c >= '0' && c <= '9')` is what you're after if you want to do that explicitly.

Comment: Do you mean a char that has the value `-46`?. That doesn't make much sense.

Comment: What you mean char -46? you mean `char a = -46;` and then `isdigit(a);`?

Comment: **-46** is a `signed char`. If you mean the string, "-46", well that's not a `char` at all, but an array of `char`.

Comment: What you need is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19206660/how-to-write-own-isnumber-function

Comment: -46 is 0xD2 which is "CAPITAL O GRAVE" in Latin-1, which isn't a digit.. is that what you want to know?

Comment: @alk: That's not what the OP is doing.

Comment: I've edited your question to clarify what you're asking for. Please check to make sure that my edit reflects what you actually meant to ask. In particular, you're trying to determine whether a character is a *digit* (like `'0'`), not whether it's a *number* (since `char` is a numeric type, all `char` values are numbers) or whether it's a representation of a number (like `"-46"`, which is a string, not a character).

Comment: @KeithThompson Yep, that`s it. Sorry for my bad interpretation.

Comment: Maybe use a regular expression and just use that to check if a string matches a number (i.e. something like `[-+]?\d+`)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The trick is that the `isdigit` function does not take an argument of type `char`. Quoting the standard ([N1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) 7.4p1:

> The header **`<ctype.h>`** declares several functions useful for
>   classifying and mapping characters. In all cases the argument is an
>   **`int`**, the value of which shall be representable as an **`unsigned char`** or shall equal the value of the macro **`EOF`**. If the
>   argument has any other value, the behavior is undefined.

The type `char` may be either signed or unsigned. If it's signed (as it very commonly is), then it can hold negative values -- and passing a negative value other than `EOF` (typically `-1`) to `isdigit`, or to any of the other functions declared in `<ctype.h>`, causes undefined behavior.

The solution is to convert the argument to `unsigned char` before passing it to `isdigit`:

```
char c = -46;
if (isdigit((unsigned char)c) {
    puts("It's a digit (?)");
}
else {
    puts("It's not a digit");
}
```

And yes, this is exactly as annoying and counterintuitive as you think it is.

Comment: It prints "It`s not a digit." But I need it to be a digit :S

Comment: @AleksandarČolović: Of course it does. `(char)-46` isn't a digit. The only digits are `'0'` through `'9'`, which in ASCII have the values `48` through `57`. *Why* do you need `-46` to be a digit? (I presume what you're asking for makes some kind of sense, but I can't see it.)

Comment: I mean i need a program to detect -46 as an number (any way possible, converting to other types allowed). I don`t need number`s specific digits. I need the whole number to be checked. Not just -, not just 4, not just 6, but whole -46. I want to sort out numbers (not digits) from a char array into a different array. I`m sorry if I`m confusing you, I`m trying to explain the best way I can.

Comment: @AleksandarČolović: Your question clearly (after edits) says you want to test a single character with the value `-46`.  The `char` value `-46` is not a digit, and you accepted both my edit and my answer based on that interpretation. If you want to know whether `-46`, stored in a `char` object, is a *number*, of course it is. But then there's nothing to test -- *any* value you can store in a `char` is a number. Do you have an example where your test should say "no"?

Answer (score 3):

The [`isdigit()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/isspace.3.html) function does not check if a number is a number, numbers are always numbers, it checks if the number is the ascii code of a character that corresponds to a numeric value or more precisely to a digit, i.e. a charachter of the following set

```
0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9
```

You can try to use [`strtol()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtol.3.html) for that purpose, like this

```
char *endptr;
char *number = "-46";

strtol(number, &endptr, 10);
if (*endptr == '\0') /* read the manual in the link to understand this please */
    printf("yes, it's a number!\n");
else
    printf("NO, `%s' is not a number!\n", number);
```

**Note**: if you read the manual or the standard specification of each function you use, you will improve your language skills, I very often see misuses of every single function from the standard library mostly because the user didn't read the manual.

Comment: This is a good answer, but not to what the OP actually meant to ask. The original version of the question was unclear; it should be clearer now.

Comment: @KeithThompson Yes I already checked the edited question, and checked your answer which is what the OP wanted to know.

Answer (score 1):

This works flawlessly

```
#include<stdio.h>
    int main(){
        char c ;
        scanf("%c",&c);
        printf("It is %d", (c>='0' && c<='9'));
    }
```