# Distinguishing if int or char / string from user input

Tags: c, validation, parsing

I'm trying to read input from the user.
I'd like to distinguish if the input provided is an int, a char or string.

I tried approaching this with scanf_s, but this didn't quite work. Is there a way to take input from the user, and tell if this is an integer, char, or string?

This is what I had so far.

```
void CheckIfInt()
{
  char returnValue = 0;

  //loop until we are given a valid input
  while(true)
  {
    scanf_s("%c", &returnValue);
    scanf_s("%C");

    if(isdigit(returnValue))
    {
      //Do something
      break;
    }

    else if(returnValue == 'a')
    {
      //Do something else
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Post the code that didn't work so we can help figure out what went wrong. :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to write own isnumber() function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19206660/how-to-write-own-isnumber-function)

Comment: Suppose this were possible/desirable. How would I enter the text string "15"?

Comment: @Purag Sorry about that. I've editted it with my code in it.

Comment: Ah, so you don't want auto-detecting input, you just want to validate numeric input. That's a good thing (and well answered).

Comment: For the record, functions like `strtol` or `atoi` might help you. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing you should do is to not use an integer pointer but rather a char pointer. This makes it easier to look at the entire input one byte at a time. So your code should look like this:

```
void ReadInteger(char* value, bool isX) { ... }
```

The next part depends on what you are looking to do, either you want to read an entire line as one input or read something until you encounter a space character. I will assume the later, which comes back to your question.

**How to tell if you just read a char**

```
int isChar(char *value) {
    return value != NULL && strlen(value) == 1 && isalpha(value[0]);
}
```

**How to tell if you just read an integer**

```
int isInteger(char *value) {
    int ans = 0;
    if (value != NULL && strlen(value) > 1) {
        while (*value && isdigit(*value)) {
            value++;
        }
        ans = (value == NULL);
    }
    ans;
}
```

**How to tell if you just read a string**

I'm feeling lazy, so this will do:

```
int isString(char *value) {
    return !isChar(value) && !isInteger(value);
}
```

**Note that the integer checking method tells if the user only typed in numbers, but doesn't tell you if that number will fit in a 32bit integer. If you want this effect, you can easily modify the code to achieve this**

Comment: Thank you. This helped out a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You can read the input into a character array by using `fgets` and then, parse it using `sscanf`.  You can look at the character array to see what type of data it is.  If you provide a sample fo input, I can show you the code.

Answer (score 0):

This should help. You can manipulate the code.

```
int myNum;
char myTerm;
if(scanf("%d%c", &myNum, &myTerm) != 2 || myTerm != '\n')
    printf("failure\n");
else
    printf("valid integer followed by enter key\n");
```

> reason : myNum will always contain an integer because it's an int

Comment: Thank you for your time. Wouldnt this code not work for inputs like 'hello1234'? It will continue reading until it reaches 1, and breaks out since 1 is a digit. It will trigger the flag to be true, and will go into the if statement below the loop